# Replacing "localhost" in text file using sed

Tags: sed, memcached, port

I have such file and I would like to replace `$GLOBALS['SERVER_MEMCACHED']='localhost';` with `$GLOBALS['SERVER_MEMCACHED']='mydomain.com';` using sed.

How to do this ? I don't want to replace the DB_HOST too.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['DB_HOST']='localhost';
$GLOBALS['DB_NAME']='database';
$GLOBALS['DB_LOGIN']='login';
$GLOBALS['DB_PASSWORD']='password';
$GLOBALS['PORT_MYSQL']='3306';
$GLOBALS['PORT_MYSQLI']='3306';
$GLOBALS['SERVER_MEMCACHED']='localhost';
$GLOBALS['PORT_MEMCACHED']='11211';
$GLOBALS['CACHE_TIME']=600;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '/SERVER_MEMCACHED/s/localhost/mydomain.com/' input
```